# Jython and python modules

Tags: java, python, interop, jython

I've just started using the `PythonInterpreter` from within my Java classes, and it works great! However, if I try to include python modules (`re`, `HTMLParser`, etc.), I'm receiving the following exception (for `re`):

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (innermost last):
  File "", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named re
```

How could I make the classes from the jython jar "see" the modules python has available?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You embed jython and you will use some Python-Modules somewere:

if you want to set the path (sys.path) in your Java-Code :

```
public void init() {
        interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());

        PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
        sys.path.append(new PyString(rootPath));
        sys.path.append(new PyString(modulesDir));
    }
```

Py is in org.python.core.

rootPath and modulesDir is where YOU want !

let rootPath point where you located the standard-jython-lib

Have a look at src/org/python/util/PyServlet.java in the Jython-Source-Code for example

Answer (score 7):

According to the [FAQ](http://www.jython.org/Project/userfaq.html#jython-modules):

> ### 4.1   What parts of the Python library are supported?
>
> The good news is that Jython now supports a large majority of the standard Python library. The bad news is that this has moved so rapidly, it's hard to keep the documentation up to date.
>
> Built-in modules (e.g. those that are written in C for CPython) are a different story. These would have to be ported to Java, or implemented with a JNI bridge in order to be used by Jython. Some built-in modules have been ported to JPython, most notably cStringIO, cPickle, struct, and binascii. It is unlikely that JNI modules will be included in Jython proper though.
>
> If you want to use a standard Python module, just try importing it. If that works, you're probably all set. You can also do a dir() on the modules to check the list of functions it implements.
>
> If there is some standard Python module that you have a real need for that doesn't work with Jython yet, please send us mail.

In other words, you *can* directly use Python modules from Jython, unless you're trying to use built-in modules, in which case you're stuck with whatever has been ported to Jython.

Comment: You can use pure python modules from jython. You can't use modules that are implemented in C. re and HTMLParser are delivered with jython.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. Leaving this answer up for reference.

Comment: @Michael you should edit your last sentence, this is misleading.

Comment: @smci Fixed the misleading sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Check your jython sys.path . Make sure that the library you want to load are in this path.
Look at [jython faq](http://www.jython.org/cgi-bin/faqw.py?req=show&file=faq02.003.htp) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer here for the solution [Importing python modules in jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256135/importing-python-modules-in-jython/33936158#33936158)

Download `ez_setup.py` from here http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

Then run `jython ez_setup.py <any module name>`.

Running it on any folder path doesn't matter.

I could install pymysql with it, no problem.