# How do I use a Python library in my Java application?

Tags: java, python, jython

What are the basic nuts and bolts of calling (running? interpreting? what can you do?) Python code from a Java program?  Are there many ways to do it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471000/jython-and-python-modules

Answer (score 4):

You can [embed Jython](http://www.jython.org/docs/embedding.html) within your Java application, rather than spawning off a separate process. Provided your library is [compatible](http://www.jython.org/docs/differences.html) with Jython, that would seem the most logical place to start.

Comment: So are you saying that it's possible that a library might not be Jython-compatible?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer to provide a link to the Jython/CPython compatibility info

Answer (score 2):

Apart from embedding Jython as mentioned by Brian, you have these options as well.

Java 1.6 has inbuilt support for scripting.
You can find more info [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/).

Spring also provides excellent support for scripting. JRuby, Groovy are supported by Spring Scripting. You can find info [here](http://www.briggs.net.nz/log/2007/11/01/scripting-in-spring/).

Answer (score 0):

And if none of the other alternatives mentioned (Jython, Spring) work, you can always run an external CPython interpreter and communicate with the JVM through:

- CORBA
- Sockets
- Pipes
- Temporary files

Also maybe you would take a look at [OpenOffice's UNO](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno)... I think it could be used outside the suite.