# Importing python modules in jython

Tags: python, import, jython, importerror, scapy

I'm having some issues importing scapy under jython. I've been doing java forever, but python for only a day or two.

The simple case to reproduce the problem is:

```
$jython

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/share/jython/Lib', '/usr/lib/site-python', '__classpath__']
>>> from scapy.all import *
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<console>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named scapy
```

If I do these exact same steps under `python`, everything works. How do I tell jython to use scapy? If it helps, I'm running ubuntu 10.04 and installed jython and scapy via `apt-get install`

Comment: Check the `sys.path` when you run vanilla Python. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've done the right thing printing sys.path.  Now you should go to your python shell, and do this:

```
$ python
>>> import scapy
>>> print scapy.__file__
```

This will show where scapy is being imported from.  The most likely problem is that your jython sys.path doesn't include the directory containing scapy.

Comment: So how then can the directory for python packages get added to the jython sys.path?

Answer (score 5):

You can do the easy_install for jython.

Run:

```
jython ez_setup.py
```

from http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

Then you will get a easy_install script under your jython/bin 
go there and

```
jython easy_install scapy
```

(or whatever module you need)

Then next time you startup jython you will be able to import it.

Comment: I had an issue under tomcat where I had to do a 'import site' first

Comment: The official docs are here: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixA.html?highlight=module#setuptools

Comment: In my case, I had to use `jython ez_setup.py scapy` instead

Comment: What good is that going to do me? I can use the PYTHONPATH and then it works to import modules. What doesn't work is that the imported module can import other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Modification from Amala's answer. His code doesn't work for me, but I solved it with something similar. This works instead.

Download `ez_setup.py` from here http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

Then run `jython ez_setup.py scapy`.

Running it on any folder path doesn't matter