# smbus on processing python mode

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, processing, smbus

Hello  is it possible to use **smbus** module on processing python mode?
When I try to `import smbus` processing puts me an error message:

```
ImportError: No module named smbus

processing.app.SketchException: ImportError: No module named smbus
at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.convertPythonSketchError(SketchRunner.java:240)
at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$2(SketchRunner.java:119)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If I create another python file that runs in the background. And that this file gets the values ​​of the **smbus** and stores them in variables. And that in the processing file I import the variables will it work?

Comment: smbus seems to be a module which is not built-in. Not all such modules work with Jython (as opposed to CPython). Forget about Processing a second -- can you use that module with Jython? It might be a simple path problem (if you used pip-install then it might not be on the Jython search path) but it might be a deeper compatibility problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3256135/4996248) might help.