# I am using jython library in java to execute a python script but it is not fetch python libraries

Tags: python, java, jython

This the java code i am using

```
    public void get_Inv_hash_ids(String token ,String url ,String url1) {
        
        try {
            String pythonPath = "/Users/milind.yadav/anaconda3/bin/python"; // Replace with the actual directory path

    
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("python.path", "/Users/milind.yadav/anaconda3/bin/python"); // Replace with the actual directory path

            // Initialize PythonInterpreter with the specified properties
//          PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), properties, new String[] { pythonPath });          
             
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

        // Execute the Python script
        interpreter.execfile("/Users/milind.yadav/Downloads/batch_id_script.py");
        
        // Get a reference to the Python function
        interpreter.eval("get invoice ids from py script");
        PyObject invoice_ids = interpreter.get("batch_id_fetcher");
        
        // Pass parameters to the Python function and call it
        PyObject result = invoice_ids.__call__(new PyString(token), new PyString(url),new PyString(url1));        
        // Convert the result to a Java integer
        String concatenated_invoice_ids = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
        
        // Print the sum
        System.out.println("Sum: " + concatenated_invoice_ids);
        
        // Clean up the interpreter
        interpreter.close();
       
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured ..."+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

And Here is the python script i am using

```
import requests
    import json
    from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
    def batch_id_fetcher(token,batchurl,url):
        invoice_object_ids=[]
        header = {"Authorization" : "Token "+token}
        batch_response=requests.get(batchurl, headers=header)
        batch_data=json.loads(batch_response.text)
        invoice_object_ids= batch_data["results"][0]["exported_invoice_ids"]
        inv_url = url+"invoices/?object_id="
        header = {"Authorization" : "Token "+token}
        invoice_hash_list=[]
        invoice_hashes=""
        
        for i in invoice_object_ids:
            n_url=inv_url+str(i)
            response = requests.get(n_url, headers=header)
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            invoice_hash_list.append(json_data["results"][0]["id"])
        invoice_hashes = ",".join(str(i) for i in invoice_hash_list)
        return invoice_hashes
```

This is the error I am getting

Exception occured ...ImportError: No module named requests

I have included all the required libraries in java as well as added all the maven dependencies
Am I missing something thing in this

Comment: You need to install the requests module into the same environment as your python binary.

Comment: yes i checked that its already there

Comment: @ewokx there is no Python binary in the jython implementation

Comment: @MilindYadav "yes i checked that its already there" there where exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing python modules in jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256135/importing-python-modules-in-jython)