# Getting Python's nltk.wordnet module working for Jython

Tags: python, jython, python-module

I've read through the FAQ for Jython and this post [Jython and python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471000/jython-and-python-modules) but am not sure how I can determine if a module is written purely in C or Python.

The problem I'm facing is mentioned here http://old.nabble.com/using-NLTK-in-Jython-td28520926.html

Can anyone that has done this shed some light on this? I'm new to Jython.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\nltk` to `sys.path` as stated in your question?  It should really be `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages`, which is the directory containing `nltk`.  If you don't want to add the entire `site-packages`, try moving the `nltk` folder to another folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Eclipse, and including the path to the root dir (nltk or site-packages) did not work. However, making jar files of both the nltk directory and the yaml directory did work. Example,

```
jar -cf nltk.jar /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk
jar -cf yaml.jar /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yaml
```

Then in my Jython code I had to add the jar files, which I added to the project's lib dir,

```
sys.path.append("/Users/peter/phd/lib/yaml.jar")
sys.path.append("/Users/peter/phd/lib/nltk.jar")
```

In addition to this I had to use the Eclipse import archive file feature to get it to see the NLTK modules.

Had a bit of a struggle with this, so hope it saves someone else some time.