# How can I integrate Java classes with Python?

Tags: java, python, django

I am building website with Python and django. There are ome data mining classes already programmed in java. Can i use those function in djnago via anything like

Comment: I'd port them to python.

Comment: Good question. SO seems to have gone nuts today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running [Django on Jython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/). I believe it should be possible to integrate Java classes in such way.

Comment: I was not able to read full docs but suppose i already have django running under linux. I have many python modules installed and many django apps. WIll i have recode everything in Jython is i can install jython and django , files , apps can stay same. Is that the case???

Comment: @user825904: That's good question. For sure you don't need recode everything, however check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471000/jython-and-python-modules/471143#471143).

Comment: Thanks buddy , i need to read full docs to see what it supports

Comment: You could run a separate Jython process to use the data mining classes and then communicate between Python and Jython with [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/), then you don't have to port your whole application for one feature.