# Java with Jython, elegant way to solve path trouble?

Tags: java, import, jython, sys.path

i have piece of Java code, using Jython to call some Python library, this library rely on external Jython classic libraryies like `re` for regular expression and others, so i have this kind of code :

```
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState()); 
    PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState(); 

    // below: so that my own library find necessary 'batteries included' Python libs
    sys.path.append(new PyString("C:/jython2.5.2/Lib")); // (path1)
    // below: i put my own Python library inside the Java package for clarity
    // and be able to package everything in jar, well, maybe is it no a good idea?
    // also i am wondering, because myfile.py remain inside /src subdirectories 
    // while after compiling Eclipse will put most in /bin subidrectories but not the *.py files
    // thus doing some:
    //    MyJythonFactory..class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString() 
    // will not help to rebuild the ..myJavaProject/src/my/domain/mypackage
    sys.path.append(new PyString("D:/eclipseWorkspace/myJavaProject/src/my/domain/mypackage")); (path2)

    interpreter.exec("from mylib import myfunc"); //(A)
    PyObject myPyFunction = interpreter.get("myfunc");
```

BTW, i do not like the fact that i need to change and hard code both path `(path1)` and `(path2)`

do you see an elegant way to avoid this and to add some 'whereami' autodetect path features (at least for `(path2)`)?

and looks like i need both (path1) and (path2) => so that (A) works!

i can also reformulated my question as what elegant way would you find to do not have any **ImportError: No module named myModule** or how to avoid hardcoding something like:

```
 PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState(); 
 sys.path.append("where/my/python/libs/live/while/they/are/at/the/same/place/as/my/current/java/class")
```

best regards

Comment: You don't need to hardcode `C:/jython2.5.2/Lib`; a properly installed `jython.jar` should know where it lives.

Comment: well, i had hadded that because it did not work without, please, what are steps that i could have missed so that it is not 'properly installed'? thx

Comment: I just ran the installer script and it worked without any trouble. Did you perhaps move the installation?

Comment: well actually it works, but as inside `mypythonmodules.py` i have for example an `import re` modules and others, it looks like i need to give Jython.jar the path to these libraries, that is why i ended with adding this path.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471000/jython-and-python-modules

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the `jython-standalone.jar` not `jython.jar` in your project classpath because `jython-standalone.jar` has Python Lib inside the jar so that you don't need append it to sys.path.

if you are using maven, you can add this to `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or you can download jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython-standalone).

for you own python module put it in the java project classpath, Jython use java classplath as `__pyclasspath__`, so you avoid hardcoding.