# import module error: calling python script using jython in a java program

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to execute a python file from netbeans using `jython` in a java program.
My code is like this:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), 
                             new String[0]);
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile("as1.py");
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "as1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

and also interdependent python files also not importing those are in same directory.

like:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile("calen.py");
```

python files are:

calen.py:

```
from as1 import * 
print ( "I am printing" + str(Moh(1000).run()))
```

as1.py:

```
from time import time
import datetime
class Moh:
    def __init__(self, n):  
        self.n = n

    def run(self):
        data = [1,2,3,4,5]
        start = time()
        for i in range(self.n):
            data.append(i)
        end = time()
        return ( end - start )/self.n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ( "I am printing" + str(Moh(1000).run()))
```

error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calen.py", line 1, in <module>
    from as1 import * 
ImportError: No module named as1
```

Comment: what version of jython are you using?

Comment: Thanks for asking - Jyhton version 2.5.3

Comment: Hope this link:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/483165/1982677] helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is essential to set "python.path" for the PythonInterpreter so that it can load your the as1 module. To do that, you have to initialize PythonInterpreter in this way:

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("python.path", PATH_TO_PARENT_DIRECTORY_OF_AS1_PY);
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), properties, new String[0]);
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile("calen.py");
```